# Async - await freezes UI in when using in OnNavigatedTo Prism method

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, prism

I'm working on a WPF application using Prism to handle things such as navigation.

I have this view that should show a list of items. I want to get the items from the db (SQL server and EF) when I navigate to it.

For that, I'm using  OnNavigatedTo, a method from the INavigationAware interface in Prism. The problem is when I click the button to navigate to it, the UI freezes. When it unfreezes, it then navigates, showing the spinner briefly before showing the view with the list of items.

This is the OnNavigatedTo method:

```
        public async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
        {
                try
                {
                    IsLoading = true;
                    _navigationJournal = navigationContext.NavigationService.Journal;
                    var items = await GetItems();
                    Items.AddRange(items);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex, "some log message");
                    Errors.Add(DefaultMessages.UnexpectedErrorMessage);
                }
                finally
                {
                    IsLoading = false;
                }
        }
```

This is the GetItems method:

```
        private async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItems()
        {
            var items = await _unitOfWork.ItemsRepository
                    .FindWithRelatedData(i => i.Processed == false);

            //MarkItemsAsProcessedCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();

            return items;
        }
```

Finally this is the FindWithRelatedData method:

```
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Items>> FindWithRelatedData(Expression<Func<Item, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return await _connection.Items
                .Include(i => i.RelatedData)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.MoreRelatedData)
                .Include(i => i.OtherRelatedData)
                    .ThenInclude(s => s.MoreRelatedData)
                        .ThenInclude(s => s.EvenMoreData)
                .Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
        }
```

Now, if I use await Task.Run(() => {}) it does work (Although supposedly Task.Run() should only be used for CPU-bound operations).

Anyway, my question is: why using await is not enough? According to [this post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) by Stephen Cleary, using async await shouldn't block the UI thread here.

Comment: What exactly happens between the clicking of the button and the request to the navigation service?

Comment: Do you mean in code, @Haukinger ? Well, clicking the button triggers a DelegateCommand in the code behind of the previous view that executes a method that only requests the navigation to the list item View.

Comment: I think of creating the view model navigated to, creating the unit of work, initializing the database connection, even creating the view... depending on where exactly you need add Task.Run to avoid the problem (RequestNavigate? GetItems? FindRelatedData?), this might all cause the freeze you're seeing.